# Efficiently find "duplicates" between two lists with dict-elements comparing just a subset of the dict-fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, compare

## What makes my question different...

...from similar ones here on StackOverflow. In the [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) below, the `dict` has 4 fields; but only 2 of them are relevant for comparing.

## The problem...

...is easy, and I always provide a solution in my MWE below, but I would like to know **if there is a more efficient, pythonic way** to handle that -- efficient in the meaning of CPU time.

Two `list()` with `dict()` elements need to be check for "duplicates." A *duplicate* is defined as if the fields `title` and `date` are equal. The content of the other fields (`flag` and `misc`) do not matter. To add another factor: the `dict` elements can have different number of fields, but `title` and `date` are always present.

## My solution

I simply translate my human words into python words (`dupli` and `data` are the two lists):

```
for d in dupli[:]:
    for e in data:
        # compare by 'title' and 'date'
        if e['title'] == d['title'] and e['date'] == d['date']:
            print('Duplicate found: {}'.format(d))
            # remove duplicates
            dupli.remove(d)
```

## My full MWE

This MWE generates the list `data` with 100 random elements. The second list `dupli` has 10 elements where 3 of them have "duplicates" (by `title` and `date` BUT NOT `misc` or `flag`) in the first list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import string


# helper function
def random_string(n):
    return ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(n)])


# Create persistent data
def create_data(n):
    container = []
    for idx in range(n):
        # create an element with title, date and some misc data
        element = {
           'title': random_string(random.randrange(35)),
           'date': [2020, 5, random.randint(1, 30)],
           'flag': (random.random() < 0.5),  # bool
           'misc': random_string(random.randrange(5)),
        }

        container.append(element)
    return container


# persistent data
data = create_data(100)

# new data elements with possible duplicates
dupli = create_data(10)

# generate 3 duplicates
for idx in [2, 5, 8]:
    dupli[idx]['title'] = data[idx*10]['title']
    dupli[idx]['date'] = data[idx*10]['date']

# MY APPROACH to check for duplicates
for d in dupli[:]:
    for e in data:
        # compare by 'title' and 'date'
        if e['title'] == d['title'] and e['date'] == d['date']:
            print('Duplicate found: {}'.format(d))
            # remove duplicates
            dupli.remove(d)

# add the rest to persistent data
data.extend(dupli)
```

## Background information

This is only an MWE. The real world data is more complex. That is why efficiency is important for me. The following numbers depending on my users of course, but just to give you and idea:

- A `dict` element has 4 to 12 fields.
- A `list` have 200 to 20.000 elements.
- There are 30 to 300 lists in my application.
- On the other side for each list there is a list with new elements: 10 to 40 elements.

Comment: does your solution works, but you want a more faster solution?

Comment: The solution works. Yes I need a faster solution if there is one. Multithreading and -processing is part of my concept because I have to handle multiple lists in the real application. But please concentrate on my MWE and just handling this two lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood your question. You can first prepare a `set()` with tuples `(<title>, <date>)` and then just check if element from `data` list is in this set - this will be *O(n)*.

For example:

```
elems = set((d['title'], tuple(d['date'])) for d in dupli)
for e in data:
    if (e['title'], tuple(e['date'])) in elems:
        print('Duplicate found: {}'.format(e))
```

Prints:

```
Duplicate found: {'title': 'ENhIdksxeNKqCgbbg', 'date': [2020, 5, 5], 'flag': True, 'misc': ''}
Duplicate found: {'title': 'MRyXAmfJjSNjrXYTNpPRQFP', 'date': [2020, 5, 3], 'flag': True, 'misc': 'oTmr'}
Duplicate found: {'title': 'IyeSazUnquqTwYXGnTjHelFGr', 'date': [2020, 5, 12], 'flag': True, 'misc': 'CdhG'}
```

---

EDIT:

In `set((d['title'], tuple(d['date'])) for d in dupli)` I must first create tuple from `d['date']`, because original type is list (unhashable) and I cannot add list to set.

Better will be storing `d['date']` as tuple originally (to skip this converting step and speed-up things):

```
'date': (2020, 5, random.randint(1, 30)),  # <-- tuple, not list
```

Comment: I do not understand your code - especially the combination of `set` and `tuple` can you explain please. And I am not sure if this is more efficient if I convert each list before comparing with another.

Comment: @buhtz Now your solution compares `len(dupli) * len(data)`, which is elements, which is `O(m*n)`. With my approach,  you first create set from `dupli` list (10 elements) and then do 100 comparisons - which is `O(m + n)`, effectively `O(n)`

Comment: `O(n)` sounds fantasctic. But I still do not understand your code. Your create a set of tuples where the second element of each tuple is a tuple itself?

Comment: @buhtz I create tuple from `d['date']` because `d['date']` is list originally - which is unhashable type (so I cannot add list to set). But I can add tuple to set.

Comment: `__hash__()` is the magic here?
I think it would help others if you could add some more explanations to your answer and your code. I mean pythonic background informations.

Comment: Could we say that the key fact here is that can speed up things if I use __hashable data__?

Comment: @buhtz To speed up things is necessary to use correct algorithms. This algorithm needs data to be hashable.